# Who and when was the first human diagnosed with hemophilia, or considered a carrier?

Tags: human-biology, hematology, history

The earliest case I can find is Queen Victoria of England, who ruled from 1837-1901. Is this the first hemophilia case on record?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The disease hemophilia has been known for much longer than that. At the time the Talmud was written, for example, it was known that if some boys in a family died from circumcision, the next were also at risk. This might have been because physicians recognized an inherited blood disorder.

Abulcasis, an Arab physicians of the 10th century, wrote about families in which male members died from bleeding out after injury.

In 1803, John Conrad Otto wrote about

> a hemorrhagic disposition existing in certain familie

Tracing the condition back three generations in that family named Smith, who lived in  Plymouth, New Hampshire. So there were definitely earlier cases where we even know the names of the patients, eben before the disease was named.

The word *haemorrhaphilia*, later shortened to *hemophilia* was first used in 1828 by Friedrich Hopff, before the birth of Queen Victoria.

Queen Victoria herself did not have the disease, though, she was a carrier. At least one of her sons had the disease and at least one of her daughters was also a carrier.

[The history of hemophilia](http://www.hemophilia.ca/en/bleeding-disorders/hemophilia-a-and-b/the-history-of-hemophilia/)

[History of Bleeding Disorders](https://www.hemophilia.org/Bleeding-Disorders/History-of-Bleeding-Disorders)